# 502 Bad Gateway for Large Requests (nginx + django)

Tags: django, nginx

I have a site running django with nginx. It is running good, but there are some sections where I get 502 Bad Gateway.

After a bit of analysis, I figure out the pages to be the ones with large contents in them while loading.

For Example: I have "college" app and "course" app. A college can have many courses, now if I try to edit a college with less than 10 courses, it works well, if I try to edit a college with more than 10 courses, it gives me 502 Bad Gateway. This has happened with all such colleges.

Any kind of help would assist. I have already tried increasing server limits.

Comment: I think this is because the process is taking a long time.

Comment: Yes, I kind of indicated that already. How can I reduce it, any idea?

Comment: If you have already tried to optimize query, and them still taken a long time, you could configure nginx, or try ajax requests, and response a 'still waiting' message, before the complete response is ready, this will give a better user experience and will avoid this nginx problem.

Comment: I have used the default django admin features, do you indicate I may need to customize the way of loading? I have this problem in Django Admin, had it been in frontend I could have used the ajax suggestion.

Comment: Yes, but as I said, have you tried to optimize django's queries? such as use indexed field to do filters, use `.get()` instead of `filter()` when it's possible. You can check [Django documentation for Database access optimization](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/optimization/)

Answer (score 1):

Try [select_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.select_related) in your FKs:

This can limit the number of round-trips to the database which can be the biggest performance problem for Django.

Comment: Welcome and thanks for the answer! As links can change, please provide the info from the link here as well. Otherwise future viewers of your answer can be left unsatisfied. Thanks.